# Primefaces Get Input Value

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i have a little problem. I have want to get the value from my inputarea i am tipping in, but it doesnt update properly. the String value is always null.

xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="No-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control"
    content="no-store,No-cache,must-revalidate,post-check=0,pre-check=0,max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/css/styles.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#{resource['Icon.png']}"
    type="image/x-icon" />
<title>#{msg['title.index']}</title>
</h:head>
<h:body style="background:#f5f5f5;">
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="#{bean.button}"
        style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px;" />

    <p:inputTextarea value="#{bean.text}" autoResize="true"
        placeholder="#{msg['label.placeholder']}" rows="3" cols="90"
        style="margin-top:250px;margin-left:5px;">
    </p:inputTextarea>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Bean:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
@SessionScoped
public class Controller {

private String text;
private String button = "Click";

public String getText() {
    System.out.println(text);
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getButton() {
    return button;
}

public void setButton(String button) {
    this.button = button;
}
}
```

It doesnt seem like he cant find my bean, because the value i gave the button is shown correctly in the browser. But teh input doesnt work. 
I have worked with jsf already and i never had problems with passing values through the bean. Another project of me is using the same method like here and it works. But in this case my inputs doesnt go to the bean. Help please.

Comment: Using a debugger, is `setText` called?

Comment: Not on keypress. But he should automaticly notice when key is pressed and update getter and setter. It doesnt.

Comment: Why should it do anything on keypress, you have no AJAX listener at all?

Comment: And compare your commandButton with your other project. Any major differences?

Comment: No there are no differences. I thought it is normal that when i am tipping some text into the inputbox, that jsf automaticly is setting teh setter and getter methods in the bean ... in my other project the text inside the inputbox is sent directly to the bean, while im a tipping and the console shows directly my text. But in this case the getter doesnt even get the input value! Maybe some properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to submit your form for the bean to take the value. Else the form is never sent.

So add an action to your command button which is the method that is gonna be called when the button is pressed.

```
    <p:commandButton value="#{bean.button}"
        style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px;" action="#{bean.submit}" />
```

Write in your bean

```
 public void submit(){}
```

your method can contain anything you want.

There are nice  [jsf tutorial here](http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/) those are the ones I used to start (I didn't finish though).

Comment: Yes this seems the right way, BUT in my project before i programmed THE SAME WAY and my problem is not the commit of the String, but the update of teh getter and setter method in the bean. In my other project i was tipping something into the input box and my console directly updated my tipping. But now it doesnt. It doesnt even take the getter or setter methods.

Comment: BTW in my commandButton is an actionListener, who should get the inputvalue and do something with it. But the button doenst even get the input value because it is always null. I also tried the binding method, which worked always for me, but in this case the same thing. The input value is always null. I think there are some properties, which are wrong in my eclipse.

Comment: I think you remember incorrectly or you didn't post the whole code. There is no actionListener in your action button. If  you want to make updates without refreshing the page take a look at f:ajax.